# Linq Max with Default Value

Tags: linq

I am trying to get the user's last login date and if no login records exist, return today's date.  I am need some help getting there. I am getting the following error and do not even have the default value component.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.DateTime?'

```
DateTime? logdate = from userlog in
                                    (from userlog in db.UserLogEntities
                                     where
                                       userlog.UserID == 1 &&
                                       userlog.Action == "Logon" &&
                                       userlog.ActionTag == "Success"
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         userlog.LogDate,
                                         Dummy = "x"
                                     })
                                group userlog by new { userlog.Dummy } into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Column1 = (DateTime?)g.Max(p => p.LogDate)
                                };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is what I came up with.  Let me know if there is a better way.

```
LastLogin = (from ul in db.UserLogEntities
                                 where ul.UserID == u.UserID &&
                                    ul.Action == "Logon" &&
                                    ul.ActionTag == "Success"
                                 select ul.LogDate).DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.Now).Max()
```

Comment: Another option: ...select (DateTime?)ul.LogDate).DefaultIfEmpty().Max()

Answer (score 1):

That is also a doable solution. But you can also use. This solution so then you do not need an aggregate function.

```
var user= (
        from ul in db.UserLogEntities
         where ul.UserID == u.UserID &&
            ul.Action == "Logon" &&
            ul.ActionTag == "Success"
        orderby ul.LogDate descending
         select ul.LogDate??DateTime.Now ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks.  one key is I need to populate with today's date if no records exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have selected a list of the dates. You should use FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() at the end of your query like this

```
select new
                                {
                                    Column1 = (DateTime?)g.Max(p => p.LogDate)
                                }.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
select new
                                    {
                                        Column1 = (DateTime?)g.Max(p => p.LogDate)
                                    }.SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Similar error: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1'...

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned this has a bug, and I don't really get the intent.