# How to make LINQ's Max-function return the default value if the sequence is empty?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I have this code:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
var max = myList.Max();
Console.Write(max);
```

I want that to ensure that if there are no elements in the list it should use the default value for `int` (0). But instead an `InvalidOperationException` is being thrown, stating that the "Sequence contains no elements".

Of course I could use `Any` or the query syntax (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542325/linq-max-with-default-value)). But I want to do it using the fluent syntax.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
var max = myList.DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
Console.Write(max);
```

LINQ's `DefaultIfEmpty`-method checks if the sequence is empty. If that is the case, it will return a singleton sequence: A sequence containing exactly one element. This one element has the default value of the sequence's type. If the sequence does contain elements, the `DefaultIfEmpty`-method will simply return the sequence itself.

See the MSDN for further information

- on the [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx) and
- the [`default` keyword in generic code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: Note that `DefaultIfEmpty` also has an overload that takes a user-provided default value (not what the OP asked for, but what I wanted)

Answer (score 9):

What about an extension?

```
public static int MaxOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Func<T, int> selector)
{
    return enumeration.Any() ? enumeration.Max(selector) : default(int);
}
```

Comment: This combined with @BillStanton's answer is the best for me - avoids double (partial) iteration of the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly at a tangent but perhaps still useful..another solution is to cast the value to nullable type;

```
var myInt = new Int[0].Max(i=>(int?)i);//myInt == null
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Enumerable.Aggregate`, you won't need any special handling for the empty list case. Try this:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
var max = myList.Aggregate(default(int), (seed, i) => (i > seed ? i : seed));
Console.Write(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension method, the solution of @AlvaroRivoir can be extendend with further generalization adding another type parameter:

```
public static K MaxOrDefault<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Func<T, K> selector) {
    return enumeration.Any() ? enumeration.Max(selector) : default;
}
```